# Использование xrange ведёт к UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-2.x, python-2.7, generate

```
def seq(n):
        yield n
        while True:
                n += 1
                yield n

def twoOfSum():
        for cur_sum in seq(0):
            for a in range(0,cur_sum):
                for b in range(0,cur_sum):
                  if a+b > cur_sum : break
                  elif a+b == cur_sum : yield a,b
                  #else : continue
            if a >= cur_sum : break

def findFrog(n):
        while True:
                for a,b in twoOfSum():
                    yield a+b*n
                    yield -a+b*n
                    yield a+(-b)*n
                    yield (-a)+(-b)*n
                    n += 1
```

Почему в данном коде, интепретатор ругается на использование range или xrange, и выдает следующие ошибки:

```
 guess = findFrog(0)
   guess.next()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 1, in <module>
  File "python", line 18, in findFrog
  File "python", line 14, in twoOfSum
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment
```

Но при замене range на seq(0), что является другим генератором, он не ругается на те же переменные ?

Comment: `range(0)` ничего не вернёт, и эти переменные просто нечем инициализировать, вот они и не инициализируются

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если коллекция пустая, то в цикле ноль итераций и нет значения, которое можно было бы `name`  присвоить:

```
>>> def f():
...     for name in []:
...         pass
...     name
...     
>>> f()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 4, in f
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'name' referenced before assignment
```

Если имя `name` было не определено, то после `for name in []: pass` цикла оно так и остаётся неопределённым.

`cur_sum` равно нулю на первой итерации внешнего цикла в функции `twoOfSum()`, поэтому `range(0, cur_sum)` создаёт пустую коллекцию, поэтому `a` имя остаётся неопределённым после `for a in range(0, cur_sum)` цикла, что ведёт к `UnboundLocalError` ошибке когда интерпретатор  до `if a >= cur_sum` строчки доходит.